# If I want to load test Web App feature that requires user login using Jmeter, Would I need to use multiple different accounts?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm planning to use Jmeter to do Load testing for a webapp, the problem is the majority of stuff that i want to load test requires user to login first and the web app doesn't allow 2 same user to login at the same time. As such would i need to create multiple different users to do this load test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application prohibits authorization to one user several times, there are two possible ways:

1. Create as many test user as you need to run concurrently and use their unique credential for each session. You can use a [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for it.
2. Ask developers to hardcode test login to allow this login without limitation.